# how to access my localhost page to another computer with different network over internet

Tags: ip, apache2, localhost, lamp, ubuntu-15.10

i have 'LAMP' server in my 'ubuntu' 15.10 OS.my local network ip like 192.168.1.25

(my computer = like eg:http://192.168.1.25/test.php   out="hello"; .but from
another computer different network enter above address 'not found')

my question is how to open my localhost webpages on another computer from different networks over internet.
Any body help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it possible.

You have to adjust port forwarding or create VPN connection between you and another computer.

Comment: I have no knowledge for that. Please give me any reference or example.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04